# Managing users, blogging, chat

Tags: premium

will Wordpress let me create users that I can manage so they can blog?  Is there a limit on the number of users you can have?  Is it easy to link it to an existing GoDaddy .COM domain?  One last question, does Wordpress support chat?

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Please note, we have a one question per post policy. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Lee ,

1 - You can create unlimited user in wordpress. Also user capacity depends on your server that how many server can handle.

2 - Yes you can easily migrate your blog with your godaddy .com domain. You will need to install wordpress there and will need to configure database.

3 - Yes of course , wordpress support chat. Many plugins are available for that like : https://wordpress.org/plugins/chat/